# Angular $index always 0 inside ng-repeat directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of items that I ng-repeat over. Inside the ng-repeat there's a directive that needs the $index passed to it. 
The repeaterIndex inside the directive is always 0, even though there are multiple items inside that array. I've tried passing the category instead of the $index as well and it's always the first category that gets passed to the directive.

**Here's the controller code**

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('ImageUploadCtrl', ['$scope', 'fooSvc',
    function ($scope, fooSvc) {
        fooSvc.getCategories().then(function(response){
            $scope.categories = response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        $scope.uploadCategoryPhoto = function(categoryIndex){
            //upload photo
        };
    }]);
```

**ng-repeat code**:

```
<li ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <my-directive repeater-index="{{$index}}" image-object="category.newFeaturedImageObj" callback="uploadCategoryPhoto"></my-directive>
</li>
```

**myDirective.js**

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            callback: '=',
            imageObject: '=',
            repeaterIndex: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/myDirective/myDirective.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.handleFileSelect = function(element) {
                var file = element.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.imageObject.image = event.target.result;
                        scope.callback(scope.repeaterIndex);
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

**myDirective.html**

```
<div>
    <input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().handleFileSelect(this)"/>
    <label for="upload">
        Upload
    </label>
</div>
```

If I use the directive in another place and give it a different callback attribute, as in callback="fooBar", the directive is still going to call uploadCategoryPhoto. It's as if all the directives on the page take the attributes of the first one.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker? So we can help you to fix it, a lot of code, difficult to figure out whole flow.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce it in a jsfiddle but I can't get it to do it. I'm not sure what the difference could be that makes it behave like that.

Comment: Try to compare versions with js fiddle

Comment: It still works with our version of angular inside the jsfiddle, the code is basically the same and still it doesn't work inside the real app, even with trying with different versions of angular.

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: No errors in the console either. If I use the directive in another place and give it a different callback attribute, as in callback="fooBar", the directive is still going to call uploadCategoryPhoto. It's as if all the directives on the page take the attributes of the first one

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved? I'm facing same issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a hard-coded ID in your directive template to associate the input with the label.
The problem is that this ID is being repeated in the ng-repeat and is not unique anymore.

The solution is to remove the ID by wrapping the label element around the input element:

**myDirective.html**

```
<div>
    <label>
        Upload
        <input type="file" accept="image/*"
           onchange="angular.element(this).scope().handleFileSelect(this)"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

or you can use your repeater-index parameter to generate unique IDs:

**myDirective.html**

```
<div>
    <input id="upload{{$repeaterIndex}}" type="file" accept="image/*"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().handleFileSelect(this)"/>
    <label for="upload{{$repeaterIndex}}">
        Upload
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look ok with your code. All work as expected.

Look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/af6rk4ec/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($timeout) {
    var me = this;
    $timeout(function() {
      me.categories = [{
        newFeaturedImageObj: {}
      }, {
        newFeaturedImageObj: {}
      }, {
        newFeaturedImageObj: {}
      }];
    }, 5000);

    this.uploadCategoryPhoto = function(categoryIndex) {
      console.log('uploadCategoryPhoto', categoryIndex);
      //upload photo
    };
  })
  .directive('myDirective', [
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          callback: '=',
          imageObject: '=',
          repeaterIndex: '@'
        },
        template: `<div>
    <input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*"
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().handleFileSelect(this)"/>
    <label for="upload">
        Upload
    </label>
</div>  `,
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.handleFileSelect = function(element) {
            var file = element.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.imageObject.image = event.target.result;
                console.log('repeaterIndex', scope.repeaterIndex);
                scope.callback(scope.repeaterIndex);
              });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    Appear after 5 seconds.
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="category in vm.categories">
        <my-directive repeater-index="{{$index}}" image-object="category.newFeaturedImageObj" callback="vm.uploadCategoryPhoto"></my-directive>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I've just tried reproducing it as well and can't seem to be able to do it. Not sure what could be causing the issue locally.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you should **declare** "categories" first. Currently, $scope.categories is being declared inside callback, but by the time call back code executes DOM has already rendered and "categories" is `undefined`. If you declare "categories" first and assign it to an array, a watcher will be registered for "categories"and when callback executes and assign data, watcher will trigger and update the DOM.

```
 angular.module('app')
.controller('ImageUploadCtrl', ['$scope', 'fooSvc',
    function ($scope, fooSvc) {
        $scope.categories = []; // declare "categories"
        fooSvc.getCategories().then(function(response){
            $scope.categories = response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        $scope.uploadCategoryPhoto = function(categoryIndex){
            //upload photo
        };
    }]);
```

Please, give it a try.

Comment: This is not issue, because it work with deffer created `categories` array. See my answer.